# 2D Array elements changing after they are set

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, cs50

The program below is meant to print a square grid of integers based on the dimension which is inputted by the user (as part of the harvard cs50 course on edx).

The array is being initialized correctly, but when it comes to printing it out, the last column always prints incorrectly. I tried debugging by putting 2 printf statements in the innermost for loop of the init() function.
It seems that after the outermost loop runs once, the entry in the last column gets decremented by one, although it was correct just before this.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it print correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main()
{
    void init(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1]);
    int dim;
    printf("Enter board dimension(max 10): ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    int arr[dim-1][dim-1];

    init(dim, arr);

    int i,j;    
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
        {
            printf("%2d  ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}

void init(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1])
{
    int i,j,p;
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (dim*dim-1)-i*dim-j;
        }   
            for(p=0;p<dim;p++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[i][p]);
                if(i>=1)
                printf("%d ", arr[i-1][p]);
            }   

    }
    printf("\n");
    if(dim%2==0)
    {
        arr[dim-1][dim-3] = 1;
        arr[dim-1][dim-2] = 2;
    }
}
```

EDIT: it should compile now

Comment: Why do you declare `void init(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1]);` in `main` function?

Comment: It doesn't even compile.  did you mean to type `i<dim-1` instead of `i<d` in main?

Comment: you need declare `void init(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1]);` before `main`

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @IvanSheigets: It's not good style, but it is valid to declare prototypes inside functions. The error is described in the text: Elements are being overwritten.

Comment: You seem to confuse the dimension of an array with the possible indices. An array of dimension `N` has `N` elements with indices `0` through `N - 1`.

Comment: I will answer this if you edit the question and post the actual code that compiles, not some made-up code which is not the code you are using. You claim that it does compile and run, yet what you have posted here does not compile.

Comment: Yes @MOehm arr[i][j] has different meanings on initialization and assignment of value. I forgot that somehow

Comment: @IvanSheigets : why shouldn't you declare functions inside main()? What difference does it make than declaring it outside anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your array with `a[dim - 1][dim - 1]`, which is one short of the desired dimension. If the user enters "4", you create a 3×3 array.

Your array is two-dimensional and of variable length. Therefore, you must pass the dimension alongside the array in functions, at least for the last dimension. You do this correctly, but the code in ´init`behaves as if the array were`a[dim][dim]`, when it's actually`a[dim - 1][dim - 1]`.

Define the array with the actual dimension, `dim` and access the elements with indices `0` through `dim - 1`. This is usually done in a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) ...
```

Seeing `>=` or `dim - 1` something similar should make you wary.

Your program now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1]);
void print(int dim, int arr[dim-1][dim-1]);

int main(void)
{
    int dim;

    printf("Enter board dimension: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    int arr[dim][dim];

    init(dim, arr);
    print(dim, arr);

    return 0;
}

void print(int dim, int arr[dim][dim])
{
    int i,j; 

    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            printf("%2d  ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void init(int dim, int arr[dim][dim])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            int ii = dim - 1 - i;
            int jj = dim - 1 - j;

            arr[i][j] = ii*dim + jj;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i had got confused with the array index starting from 0 and arr[i][j] denoting the array size on initialization.